# Fetch selected value of p:selectOneMenu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

i need to fetch a value of a `<p:selectOneMenu>` in javascript but the result that i get is **null**. I am able to call the function but when i am trying to access the value of the `<p:selectOneMenu>`. i get null in alert box.

Please find the below code.

```
<p:outputLabel for="year" value="Year: " /> 
        <p:selectOneMenu id="year" style="width:150px   " value="#{someBean.year}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2014" itemValue="2014"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2013" itemValue="2013"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2012" itemValue="2012"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2011" itemValue="2011"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2010" itemValue="2010"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2009" itemValue="2009"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Javascript function:

```
function validateYearMonth()
{
    var yearValue1=document.getElementById('Form:year_input');
    var yearValue2=document.getElementById('Form:year');
    alert(yearValue1);
    alert(yearValue2);

}
```

Call to function:

```
 <p:commandButton id="Submit" action="#{someBean.functionName}"
    onclick="validateYearMonth()" value="Submit" ajax="false" style="float:right;">
  </p:commandButton>
```

I dont understand whats wrong. **while i am able fetch the element** if i am doing

```
var yearValue1=document.getElementById('Form:year_input');
```

but i am not able to fetch the value. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @BalusC : I tried your method..I have updated my question with your solution that you gave but even for them i get null. Year is my entity ID and year_input is the id that i get after doing view source. Why is that i am receiving null?

Comment: @BalusC : No as per the changes made i am not getting undefined. But i am getting null in both alerts mentioned in validateYearMonth function.

Comment: @BalusC : Is there anything that i can do for solving the issue?. Please guide.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple approach would be setting a `widgetVar` name and then get the current value!

```xhtml
<p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="yearWV">
```

in *javascript* (PF 4 and higher)

```javascript
PF('yearWV').value
```

You can test this right away in your console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    **BEST WORKING SOLUTION :**

       <p:selectOneMenu id="year" style="width:150px" value="#{someBean.year}" widgetVar="test" onchange="myTestFunction()">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2014" itemValue="2014"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2013" itemValue="2013"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2012" itemValue="2012"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2011" itemValue="2011"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2010" itemValue="2010"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2009" itemValue="2009"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

Java Script Code:

function myTestFunction()
        {

        var selectedValue=PF('test').getSelectedValue();

        alert(selectedValue);

        }

    [**For more information please check this link ** https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=39793][1]
```

Comment: Got undefined with value, getSelectedValue did the job, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add return keyword in onclick event. Eg.

```
         <p:commandButton id="Submit" action="#{someBean.functionName}"
          onclick="return validateYearMonth()" value="Submit" ajax="false" style="float:right;">
    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Tried but still i get undefined.

Answer (score -1):

In your JSF form, set prependId=false. i.e.

```
<h:form id="myform" prependId="false">
```

If you do not set prependId to false, what you get in your generated HTML dropdown's id will be

```
<select id="myform:year">
```

In this case, in your javascript you have to get the element using document.getElementById("myform:year");

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Helped me in some progress. I did what you said but now i get a null in alert box. Anything that i have missed.

Comment: @Shirish your `alert` is with the variable undefined. e.g using `year` but it should be `yearValue`. See on `month` case too.

Comment: Try this: `var e = document.getElementById("year");`
`var yearValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: I have updated my answer. The main issue that i am facing is that i receive null at the beginning itself. what can be the problem?

Comment: I suspect if you are using the right id in the javascript for the select list component. If you are using Firefox, you can right click on the the select list and select "Inspect Element". I put your javascript in JSFiddle and did some modification to let you see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/TL8r2/